# Loop inside a loop showing wrong data

Tags: php, loops, pdf

I have a list of PDF files that are categorized into lists.

Like this:

```
Terms:
PDF1.pdf
PDF2.pdf

Conditions:
PDF1.pdf
PDF3.pdf
```

So I first looped all the categories to show the titles of the categories on my page, and within that loop I looped the pdf file urls (just for testing purposes, the final code will get anchor tags etc).

The problem is that my code shows all pdf files on all titles. Not just the pdf files that belong to them. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to empty `$attach` after every loop?

My code:

```
foreach($manualcr as $mantitle){
  if($mantitle['id'] != ''){
    $attachoverzicht .= '<h3>'.$mantitle['title'].'</h3>';
    foreach($manucr as $attach){
      if($attach['id'] != ''){
        $attachoverzicht .= '<li>'.$attach['url'].'</li>';
      }
    }
  }
}
echo $attachoverzicht;
```

`$manualcr` contains all the  category titles and `manucr` contains all the pdf data.

The var dump result of `$manualcr` is here

```
    array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(30) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "182"
    ["asset_id"]=>
    string(3) "299"
    ["title"]=>
    string(18) "Terms & Conditions"
    ["alias"]=>
    string(16) "terms-conditions"
    ["introtext"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["fulltext"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["state"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["catid"]=>
    string(2) "42"
    ["created"]=>
    string(19) "2017-02-16 13:54:45"
    ["created_by"]=>
    string(3) "360"
    ["created_by_alias"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["modified"]=>
    string(19) "2017-02-16 13:56:43"
    ["modified_by"]=>
    string(3) "360"
    ["checked_out"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["checked_out_time"]=>
    string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    ["publish_up"]=>
    string(19) "2017-02-16 13:54:45"
    ["publish_down"]=>
    string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    ["images"]=>
    string(173) "{"image_intro":"","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}"
    ["urls"]=>
    string(121) "{"urla":false,"urlatext":"","targeta":"","urlb":false,"urlbtext":"","targetb":"","urlc":false,"urlctext":"","targetc":""}"
    ["attribs"]=>
    string(593) "{"show_title":"","link_titles":"","show_tags":"","show_intro":"","info_block_position":"","show_category":"","link_category":"","show_parent_category":"","link_parent_category":"","show_author":"","link_author":"","show_create_date":"","show_modify_date":"","show_publish_date":"","show_item_navigation":"","show_icons":"","show_print_icon":"","show_email_icon":"","show_vote":"","show_hits":"","show_noauth":"","urls_position":"","alternative_readmore":"","article_layout":"","show_publishing_options":"","show_article_options":"","show_urls_images_backend":"","show_urls_images_frontend":""}"
    ["version"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["ordering"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["metakey"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["metadesc"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["access"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["hits"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["metadata"]=>
    string(53) "{"robots":"","author":"","rights":"","xreference":""}"
    ["featured"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["language"]=>
    string(1) "*"
    ["xreference"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [1]=>
  array(30) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "181"
    ["asset_id"]=>
    string(3) "298"
    ["title"]=>
    string(8) "Shackles"
    ["alias"]=>
    string(8) "shackles"
    ["introtext"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["fulltext"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["state"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["catid"]=>
    string(2) "42"
    ["created"]=>
    string(19) "2017-02-16 13:54:31"
    ["created_by"]=>
    string(3) "360"
    ["created_by_alias"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["modified"]=>
    string(19) "2017-02-16 13:57:00"
    ["modified_by"]=>
    string(3) "360"
    ["checked_out"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["checked_out_time"]=>
    string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    ["publish_up"]=>
    string(19) "2017-02-16 13:54:31"
    ["publish_down"]=>
    string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    ["images"]=>
    string(173) "{"image_intro":"","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}"
    ["urls"]=>
    string(121) "{"urla":false,"urlatext":"","targeta":"","urlb":false,"urlbtext":"","targetb":"","urlc":false,"urlctext":"","targetc":""}"
    ["attribs"]=>
    string(593) "{"show_title":"","link_titles":"","show_tags":"","show_intro":"","info_block_position":"","show_category":"","link_category":"","show_parent_category":"","link_parent_category":"","show_author":"","link_author":"","show_create_date":"","show_modify_date":"","show_publish_date":"","show_item_navigation":"","show_icons":"","show_print_icon":"","show_email_icon":"","show_vote":"","show_hits":"","show_noauth":"","urls_position":"","alternative_readmore":"","article_layout":"","show_publishing_options":"","show_article_options":"","show_urls_images_backend":"","show_urls_images_frontend":""}"
    ["version"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["ordering"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["metakey"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["metadesc"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["access"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["hits"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["metadata"]=>
    string(53) "{"robots":"","author":"","rights":"","xreference":""}"
    ["featured"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["language"]=>
    string(1) "*"
    ["xreference"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [2]=>
  NULL
}
```

and the result of `$manucr`

```
    array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(26) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["filename"]=>
    string(13) "dummy_pdf.pdf"
    ["filename_sys"]=>
    string(71) "/home/website/public_html/cms/attachments/article/182/dummy_pdf.pdf"
    ["file_type"]=>
    string(15) "application/pdf"
    ["file_size"]=>
    string(5) "16555"
    ["url"]=>
    string(37) "attachments/article/182/dummy_pdf.pdf"
    ["uri_type"]=>
    string(4) "file"
    ["url_valid"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["url_relative"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["url_verify"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["display_name"]=>
    string(9) "Test naam"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["icon_filename"]=>
    string(7) "pdf.gif"
    ["access"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["state"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["user_field_1"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["user_field_2"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["user_field_3"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["parent_type"]=>
    string(11) "com_content"
    ["parent_entity"]=>
    string(7) "article"
    ["parent_id"]=>
    string(3) "182"
    ["created"]=>
    string(19) "2017-02-16 13:56:03"
    ["created_by"]=>
    string(3) "360"
    ["modified"]=>
    string(19) "2017-02-16 13:56:03"
    ["modified_by"]=>
    string(3) "360"
    ["download_count"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(26) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["filename"]=>
    string(14) "dummy_pdf1.pdf"
    ["filename_sys"]=>
    string(72) "/home/website/public_html/cms/attachments/article/182/dummy_pdf1.pdf"
    ["file_type"]=>
    string(15) "application/pdf"
    ["file_size"]=>
    string(5) "16555"
    ["url"]=>
    string(38) "attachments/article/182/dummy_pdf1.pdf"
    ["uri_type"]=>
    string(4) "file"
    ["url_valid"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["url_relative"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["url_verify"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["display_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["icon_filename"]=>
    string(7) "pdf.gif"
    ["access"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["state"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["user_field_1"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["user_field_2"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["user_field_3"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["parent_type"]=>
    string(11) "com_content"
    ["parent_entity"]=>
    string(7) "article"
    ["parent_id"]=>
    string(3) "182"
    ["created"]=>
    string(19) "2017-02-16 13:56:39"
    ["created_by"]=>
    string(3) "360"
    ["modified"]=>
    string(19) "2017-02-16 13:56:39"
    ["modified_by"]=>
    string(3) "360"
    ["download_count"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(26) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["filename"]=>
    string(13) "dummy_pdf.pdf"
    ["filename_sys"]=>
    string(71) "/home/website/public_html/cms/attachments/article/181/dummy_pdf.pdf"
    ["file_type"]=>
    string(15) "application/pdf"
    ["file_size"]=>
    string(5) "16555"
    ["url"]=>
    string(37) "attachments/article/181/dummy_pdf.pdf"
    ["uri_type"]=>
    string(4) "file"
    ["url_valid"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["url_relative"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["url_verify"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["display_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["icon_filename"]=>
    string(7) "pdf.gif"
    ["access"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["state"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["user_field_1"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["user_field_2"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["user_field_3"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["parent_type"]=>
    string(11) "com_content"
    ["parent_entity"]=>
    string(7) "article"
    ["parent_id"]=>
    string(3) "181"
    ["created"]=>
    string(19) "2017-02-16 13:56:55"
    ["created_by"]=>
    string(3) "360"
    ["modified"]=>
    string(19) "2017-02-16 13:56:55"
    ["modified_by"]=>
    string(3) "360"
    ["download_count"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [3]=>
  NULL
}
```

Comment: Could you show the output of `var_dump($manualcr);` and `var_dump($manucr);` ? It seems you are not checking the condition where your `$manucr` category is the same as your `$manualcr` one.

Comment: Yes I'll add them to my question. @roberto06

Comment: Could you at least change your database access call to `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` or if PDO fetch using `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` so the array only contains ONE occurance of each columns data. It will make your codes memory usage drop as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your `var_dump` outputs, I assume your corresponding fields are `$mantitle['id']` and `$attach['parent_id']`.

You have to check for this in your second loop, as such :

```
foreach($manualcr as $mantitle){
  if($mantitle['id'] != ''){
    $attachoverzicht .= '<h3>'.$mantitle['title'].'</h3>';
    foreach($manucr as $attach){
      if($attach['id'] != '' && $attach['parent_id'] == $mantitle['id']){ // Check for condition added here
        $attachoverzicht .= '<li>'.$attach['url'].'</li>';
      }
    }
  }
}
echo $attachoverzicht;
```

Comment: Thanks, makes perfect sense.